# USB-C data-only cable for phone to battery-powered accessory

Tags: usb-device, usb-c

Basically I have phone and a battery powered USB/Bluetooth controller. The Bluetooth connection isn't great, so I want to use it wired. However it drains my phone battery to recharge its own. I'd prefer to use two separate batteries. Both are USB-C, the device is 2.0-only. Would this schematic work if I made a cable or series of cables ("Quick Switch" adapter -> PortaPow power blocker -> A-to-C cable) like this, assuming the controller can take it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmf2Sb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It'll work most of the time.  If the host side loses power (battery drained or comes loose) which the device is still powered, you'll be violating the USB rules and potentially breaking the host-side ICs connected to the USB data lines.  On a self-powered device, the data line pullups are supposed to connect to VBUS coming from the host side, not to the device-side independent power --- your funny cable is defeating this.

Comment: what would you propose as an alternative?

Comment: You have to connect the connectors' GND pins together through your cable.

Comment: ok nevermind the whole exercise was pointless anyway. i tried the portapow after it arrived and the controller just went into bluetooth mode instead of wired. i just have to use bluetooth or take its battery out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work. The VBUS pin on the device side is disconnected until it detects a valid connection, and it will not detect a valid connection until the resistor gets power.

You need to connect this resistor to a 5V source, like the VBUS pin from the plug to the host side. *Note that most devices depends on receiving a voltage on VBUS before the enable USB communications, so it might need more work*